# Apex unexpected token '<'

Tags: apex, execute-anonymous

Apex Unexpected token '<'.

I'm getting this error on anonymous window.

> Line: 3, Column: 13 Unexpected token '<'.

using this code:

```
String devName1 = 'Mass_Parcel_Update';

List<Block__mdt> dynamicMdt = [SELECT Block__c,
                                                       Block__c WHERE
                                                       DeveloperName = devName1 FROM 
                                                       Block__mdt LIMIT 1];
```

Comment: I guess you have written query in wrong way. You have to use From first and then filter record based on Where. `List<LMS_Dynamic_Datatable_Config__mdt> dynamicMdt = [SELECT LMS_Field_Label__c,DeveloperName, LMS_Field_Value__c  FROM LMS_Dynamic_Datatable_Config__mdt WHERE DeveloperName = :devName1  LIMIT 1];`

Comment: Thanks! it is working now.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you forgot to add a colon when mentioning the `devName1` [variable in the query](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_variables.htm). Try to use mention it like this `:devName1` in your query.

And one more thing, `WHERE` [should be](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql.htm) after `FROM`

By the way, you can use [Custom Metadata Type Methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_custom_metadata_types.htm) instead of the SOQL to get the settings. For example, like this, in your case:

```
LMS_Dynamic_Datatable_Config__mdt mc = LMS_Dynamic_Datatable_Config__mdt.getInstance(devName1);
```

Comment: Thanks! it is working now.